# Spacy NER - How to Identify People names using matcher patterns

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to identify the **People names** using following matcher patterns in Spacy. but this is identifying other words like 'my', and 'name'. Can anyone help me identify the issue in the pattern.?

```
person_pattern = [ 
    {"label":"PERSON", 
     "pattern": [{'POS':'PROPN'}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}],
     "comment": "Spacy's in-built PERSON capure"
    }]
```

**Example:**

```
My Name as in Google Record is Hannah, but i would like to modify Name as in AADHAR Hanna. My CDS ID is JANAN34
```

**Result/Behavior:**

```
text: My, pos_: PRON, ent_type_: PERSON

text: Name, pos_: NOUN, ent_type_: PERSON
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the built-in entity detection? Also, can you give an example sentence? I'm a little unclear how the above would match words like "my" or "name".

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have updated the question with an example and result, please check. I have multiple other patterns to identify words like employee id, etc. I wonder if built-in entity detectors will identify the these type of words

Answer (score 0):

I ran some sample code using your pattern and it seems that your pattern isn't matching anything, so the problem isn't with the Matcher. The problem seems to be with spaCy's NER models.

Your text is kind of unusual - "My Name as in..." is not normal capitalization, and the model seems to mistake it for an actual name. If you change "Name" to "name" then it's no longer detected as an entity.

I think this is just a case of your data not being similar to spaCy's training data, which is more like newspaper articles that use formal capitalization. The v3 models are a little weak to case changes at the moment because some data augmentation was accidentally left out when training them, but that should be resolved in the v3.1 release coming up soon.

If you have training data, you might look at training using spaCy's [data augmentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training#data-augmentation) to be more resilient to unusual data.